# Does VB .NET have different implicit conversion rules from C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I am porting some code from VB .NET to C# and found that VB seems to allow implicit conversion of enums to integers, for example the following code compiles without even a warning in VB but it's an error to do this in C#.

```
Option Strict On

Module Module1
    Enum Alpha
        A
        B
        C
    End Enum

    Sub Main()
        Dim val As Integer = Alpha.A
    End Sub
End Module
```

I thought with `Option Strict On`, the rules should be the same but it doesn't seem to be the case. Are there any  other differences?

Comment: *Are there any other differences?* - AFAIK, yes of course!, many differences, more than that can have an answer here ;).

Comment: Can I ask reason for converting vb.net to c#. You can reference vb.net project in c# projects as well. Seems converting is a task which produce no value

Comment: VB was created to simplify few parts of the programming. Are you asking for differences within this code snippet or the major differences between them?

Comment: I searched MSDN for rules of implicit conversion in VB but a could find an example of converting a float to double or something like that. If it's reasonably possible I'd like a summary of the  major differences with strict on or a reference to something online  that outlines the VB rules.

Comment: It's not so much a _conversion_ as a difference in the way the language works. Enums in VB default to 32-bit signed integers.